Search for an article on AI failure in crowd detection
I'm looking for an example I read (or maybe saw on YouTube) several years ago illustrating the limits of artificial intelligence, but I cannot find the source or any reference to this story (it may be that the original source was in French).
In this example, an AI had been developed to manage the opening of gates (I think it was on the London Underground) based on CCTV images. Everything worked fine until one day the gates failed to open despite the presence of a crowd. The engineers then discovered that the AI had learned to read the time on a clock visible in the videos, rather than detecting the presence of a crowd. The crowd at that time of day was exceptional and, I seem to remember, due to a football match that had been postponed.
I tried searching with a lot of keywords, but I couldn't find any articles on this story. Does this story mean anything to anyone?
Thanks in advance for your help!
